# JSON Response Has Escaped Quotations Using Jackson and JAX-RS Exception Mapper

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, resteasy, jackson2

I have a simple requirement where, if application encounters an exception, my JAX-RS Rest endpoint should return a custom JSON response with 500 HTTP header status.

Data needed to construct the response comes from an object with several properties (see below). The problem is, I am only interested in one or two values from each property (out of several dozens). And I cannot modify any of these models/classes (some have a Jackson annotation for JSON processing, e.g. null properties should be discarded during serialization).

```
public class MainObject {
  private FirstProperty firstProperty;
  private SecondProperty secondProperty;
  private ThirdProperty thirdProperty;
  // other codes
  public String toString() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try { return mapper.writeValueAsString(this); }
    catch (Exception e) {  return null; }
  }
}

public class FirstProperty {
  private boolean bol = true;
  private double dob = 5.0;
  private List<String> subProperty;
  // other properties
  public String toString() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try { return mapper.writeValueAsString(this); }
    catch (Exception e) {  return null; }
  }
}

@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class SecondProperty {
  private String str;
  private List<String> subProperty;
  // other properties
  public String toString() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try { return mapper.writeValueAsString(this); }
    catch (Exception e) {  return null; }
  }
}

@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class ThirdProperty {
  private int intProp = true;
  private List<String> subProperty;
  // other properties
  public String toString() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try { return mapper.writeValueAsString(this); }
    catch (Exception e) {  return null; }
  }
}
```

The expected JSON that I should be seeing coming back is on the client side (say, a browser -- testing in Edge):

```
{
  "firstProperty" : { "subProperty" : [ "val1" ] },
  "secondProperty" : { "str" : "val2", "subproperty" : [ "val3", "val6" ] },
  "thirdProperty" : { "subProperty" : [ "val4" ] }
}
```

Instead, all my field names and their values have their quotations escaped, and extra double quotes around the entire value, e.g.:

```
{
  "firstProperty" : "{ \"subProperty\" : [ \"val1\" ] }",
  "secondProperty" : "{ \"str\" : \"val2\", \"subproperty\" : [ \"val3\", \"val6\" ] }",
  "thirdProperty" : "{ \"subProperty\" : [ \"val4\" ] }"
}
```

Please note the extra `"` before and after the curly brackets. My environment is:

```
Java 1.8.45
FasterXML Jackson 2.9.8
Spring Boot 2.0.1
RestEasy (JBoss) JAX-RS
JBoss 6.4
```

I eliminated the majority of "noise" in the code to see at what point this happens. This is the controller:

```
@Path("/")
public class MainController {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Path("/rest/path")
  public MainObject getMainObject throws MyCustomException {
    // A service call that throws MyCustomException
  }
}
```

And JAX-RS `ExceptionMapper` where I send the response back:

```
@Provider
public class MyCustomExceptionMapper extends ExceptionMapper<MyCustomException> {

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(MyCustomException ex) {
    HashMap<String, Object> responseBody = new HashMap<>();

    String strEx = ex.getStrEx(); // Comes from SecondProperty.str stored in MyCustomException, not that it matters

    // Instantiate an empty object that contains 
    MainObject obj = new MainObject();
    obj.getFirstProperty().setSubProperty(ex.getStrs());
    obj.getSecondProperty().setStr(strEx);
    obj.getSecondProperty().setSubProperty(ex.getStrs());
    obj.getThirdProperty().setSubProperty(ex.getStrs());

    responseBody.put("firstProperty", serializeFirstProperty(obj.getFirstProperty()));
    responseBody.put("secondProperty", serializeSecondProperty(obj.getSecondProperty()));
    responseBody.put("thirdProperty", serializeThirdProperty(obj.getThirdProperty()));

    Response response = Response.status(/* 500 status */).entity(responseBody).build();

    return response;
  }

}
```

Since I only need to send back a very small subset of overall properties from each of my types, I created a custom `StdSerializer` that would only populate a needed property. For brevity, I only do `serializeFirstProperty()` but they are all more or less identical:

```
private StdSerializer<FirstProperty> getFPSerializer(FirstProperty firstProperty) {
  return new StdSerializer<FirstProperty>(FirstProperty.class) {
    @Override
    public void serialize(FirstProperty value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {

      gen.writeStartObject();
      if (/* there are items in FirstProperty.subProperty */) {
        gen.writeArrayFieldStart("subProperty");
        for (String str : value.getSubProperty()) {
          gen.writeString(str);
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
      }
      gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

private <T> ObjectMapper getCustomOM(StdSerializer<?> serializer) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  SimpleModule sm = new SimpleModule();
  sm.addSerializer(serializer);
  mapper.registerModule(module);

  return mapper;
}
```

Then use these helper methods like:

```
private String serializeFirstProperty(FirstProperty firstProperty) {
  ObjectMapper mapper = getCustomOM(getFPSerializer(firstProperty));

  String ser = null;
  try { ser = mapper.writeValueAsString(firstProperty); }
  catch (JsonProcessingException e) { return null; }
  return ser;
}
```

I have tried countless of configurations with `ObjectMapper`, e.g. `disable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER)` (couldn't find any relevant flag for `JsonGenerator` which I really want to disable in a similar fashion).

Or explicitly returning `Object` from `serializeFirstProperty()`, or replacing all the `\"` with `"` in `serializeFirstProperty()` when `ser` is returned.

Or set custom `StdSerializer`'s `JsonGenerator.setCharacterEscapes(new CharacterEscapes() { //... }` or play around with JAX-RS `Response` at no avail. I always seem to get a "string" value with quotations, e.g.:

```
"firstProperty" : "{ \"subProperty\" : [ \"val1\" ] }"
```

If I simply just do

```
responseBody.put("firstProperty", mapper.writeValueAsString(obj.getFirstProperty()));
```

somehow this produces the right JSON output, however, it includes a lot of unnecessary properties which I don't want in this exception handling case.

Funny thing is, when I peer into `response` (or `responseBody` map), everything looks right (I don't see values having double quotations).

Please also note that not only I can't modify the models, but some of their properties are instantiated during creation with default values, so not-null inclusion doesn't work, and they will appear in the final JSON if I don't use a custom serialization.

Does anyone know what's causing this escaped and extra quotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I misunderstood the question in the first attempt of answering it.

The problem is that you serialize a property as string (using `mapper.writeValueAsString(this)` and then add it to the `responseBody` which you think of being string to **json object** map but it is a string to **Java object** map. In your case at runtime it is a string mapping to another string (the serialized json object is represented as Java string) and a Java string is a Java object as well.

What you want to do instead is to construct a Java object `responseBody` instead of a map. It should act as a DTO having all the specific properties etc and then serializing it in in one action using the mapper. Because if you first serialize a property to a json string than it it is just a string from the Java point of view and the mapper has no chance to interpret it as a json object.

Comment: Do you mean `mapper.writeValue(firstProperty)`? And does `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` have `writeValue(Object)`? I have never encountered one in the API or documentations.

Comment: Or are you referring to model's `toString()` method (as I mentioned, I cannot modify those classes as they return the object that way back to the client anyway, and this change only applies in case of exception handling)?

Comment: If I put a break point at each of models' `toString()`, they never get hit. As a matter of fact, I don't see a place where I'm invoking any of the model's `toString()` (if you see it, please point it out). And yes, I was under the impression that it should be "string to Java object", hence `Map<String, Object>`. I see what you are asking here, and that is, to basically create another model and serialize it like one of the existing ones. I'll give it a try.

Comment: A side note: If I change JAX-RS' media type with `Response`, e.g. `Response.type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`, then it returns the right format to the browser/client. However, since it's `text/plain` rather than `application/json`, the React component craps out.

Comment: The `toString` methods are not called, because jackson does not use them for serialization, but utilizes the Java reflection API to access an objects structure and the fields' contents during runtime. Your problem sits in your manually created `responseBody` map which you fill with Strings as values. And these strings will be escaped. You rather want a custom `ResultBody` object (e.g. call it `ResponseBodyDTO`) and have its properties holding the actual **java** objects. Do not serialize the properties beforehand.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I suppose, I could have used the same `MainObject` and develop a custom serializer around it to only populate specific fields only and omit everything else. However, there is this one extra value that I need to include in the response (which I didn't include in my question) that is not part of `MainObject`. I guess other than reflectively append it to `MainObject` then run a custom serializer, I don't see how this can be done with manipulating only `MainObject'. I think as you mentioned, it's best to just create another DTO model to handle these exception cases.